# How can I maintain custom UITableViewCell's internal control layout in editing mode?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` with a couple of multiline labels, auto layout, *etc.* I have the multiline labels constrained so that their trailing edge is less than the trailing edge of the cell's content view so that they wrap properly. This is all working correctly, as far as I can tell.

I'm running into a problem when I put the table view in editing mode though. What I would like to have happen is for the cell's contents to just shift to the right to make room for the delete control *without changing their layout*. What actually happens is that the cell's content view appears to shrink in size to make room for the delete control. This causes the labels to reflow their contents and sometimes causes the layout to get screwed up if the label tries to change its height.

Is there a recommended way to just shift the contents when entering editing mode, rather than re-laying out at a smaller width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the cell's `contentView` is resized when the delete button appears.

One idea is to add an additional view to the cell's `contentView`. This extra view should contain all of your nicely laid out subviews.

Set this extra view's constraints such that the left anchor is tied to the contentView's left anchor. But set this extra view's width to match the cell's width and not the contentView's width.

This should allow the whole extra view (and all your nice little subviews) to shift as a whole to the right when entering editing mode and the delete icon appears.

But this may bring up a new problem. Once the user taps the delete icon, the cell will show a Delete button on the right. So you may need to redo the constraints so the right anchor is set and not the left. This change in constraints will probably need to be done in the custom cell's `willTransition` method.

I'm sure there are some details to work out but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: It turns out that, at least on iOS 12, I don't even need to change the leading and trailing constraints for the fixed-width container when the cell transitions between modes. Just putting all of my controls into a container view that's the same width as the cell itself maintains the layout during editing.